# Executing multiple pytest test files by using one "master" file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have multiple test files in the test folder. My directory structure is like:

```
Tests/
  run-tests.py
  pytest.ini
  /TestCases
    TestCase1.py
    TestCase2.py
```

My *run-tests.py* file contains:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import    
import pytest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main(args=['TestsCases'])
```

So when I run *run-tests.py* from console:

```
python3.8 -m pytest Tests/run-tests.py
```

tests are not executed. Of course I could create shell script and call them inside the script by explicitly calling them but this is what I do not want to do.
TestCase1.py and other file contains tests which use *pytest* framework and are defined as functions. I am not using classes inside.

**So question: is it possible to execute TestCase*.py files by using run-test.py file?**

Also I wonder how the pytest.xml files will be generated. My pytest.ini file contains:

```
addopts = -v -s -ra --junitxml=Tests/test-reports/pytest.xml
```

Would be very nice to be able to merge all TestCase*.py exports into single one report xml file.
I am afraid that every TestCase*.py file will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: Run `python3.8 Tests/run-tests.py`

Comment: You will get one report per test run, not per test module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Inside my *run-tests.py* file I have a loop from which I call every test:

```
test_cases_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/TestCases/'
for name in os.listdir(test_cases_folder):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'Test*.py'):
        pytest.main(
            [test_cases_folder+'TestCase'+str(i)+'.py', '--url='+args.server, '--user='+args.user, '--headless='+args.headless]
        )
```

also I am executing script as a module, not by calling file directly:

```
python3.8 -m Tests.run-tests --server=<hostname> --user=<username> --headless=False|True
```

hopefully it will help somebody